# Calculate Conditional Cumulative Sum SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

[This is main table which have mainval to perform conditional cumulative sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCZcQ.png)

And the other table I have value example I have subval 16 that value needs to subtract from main-val if (substract value)  subval - mainval > 0 then allow and update substract val

And I need output like this

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULUAE.png)

Need to calculate column cumulative sum with some condition and update that value for next row and use it.

Here provide sample data and in other field value subval=16 this value need to calculate on mainval in conditional calculation.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MainTblcnt](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [mainid] [int] NULL,
    [mainval] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_MainTblcnt] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MainTblcnt] ON 
GO

INSERT [dbo].[MainTblcnt] ([id], [mainid], [mainval])
VALUES
(1, 477, 20),
(2, 477, 20),
(3, 477, 6),
(4, 477, 5),
(5, 477, 8),
(6, 477, 3),
(7, 477, 2),
(8, 477, 10)
GO

SET IDENTITY_INsERT [dbo].[MainTblcnt] OFF
GO
```

Comment: Providing data instead of images of it helps to get much faster recommendations from the community.it is one of the reasons that you get Downvote

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without a proper description of the logic and proper sample data. But you can use window functions for this.

It seems a combination of `SUM` `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAG` should work

```sql
SELECT
  *,
  RemainVal = LAG(RunningRemain) OVER (PARTITION BY mainid ORDER BY id DESC)
FROM (
    SELECT
      *,
      RunningRemain =
        SUM(mainval) OVER (PARTITION BY mainid ORDER BY id DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
        -
        FIRST_VALUE(mainval) OVER (PARTITION BY mainid ORDER BY id DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM YourTable t
) t;
```

Comment: in short i need Order status deliverable or not with reducing quantity from stock without cursor or While loop, you query not working as per my requirement. i am having recursive query logic but i want to use from other logic

Comment: You haven't shown your requirements properly. Please use text not images, and please explain the logic more clearly